# Printing float values in Python (Mapbox geo-coordinates)

Tags: python, json, mapbox, geocoding

I'm scraping a website in order to get address which I then am running through the MapBox geo-coder using their API.

The basic code is:

```
geocoder = mapbox.Geocoder(access_token='my_token')


response = geocoder.forward(address)
result = response.json()
```

I'm feeding in the addresses on the fly, as I scrape the webpage.

When I print `result`, my geo-code output is:

```
{u'attribution': u'NOTICE: \xa9 2019 Mapbox and its suppliers. All rights reserved. Use of this data is subject to the Mapbox Terms of Service (https://www.mapbox.com/about/maps/). This response and the information it contains may not be retained. POI(s) provided by Foursquare.', u'query': [u'1151', u'folsom', u'st', u'san', u'francisco', u'ca', u'94103'], u'type': u'FeatureCollection', u'features': [{u'center': [-122.408767, 37.775679], u'geometry': {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [-122.408767, 37.775679]}, u'text': u'Folsom Street', u'place_type': [u'address'], u'properties': {u'accuracy': u'point'}, u'context': [{u'text': u'South of Market', u'id': u'neighborhood.293577'}, {u'text': u'94103', u'id': u'postcode.13892342768265050'}, {u'text': u'San Francisco', u'wikidata': u'Q62', u'id': u'place.15734669613361910'}, {u'short_code': u'US-CA', u'text': u'California', u'wikidata': u'Q99', u'id': u'region.11319063928738010'}, {u'short_code': u'us', u'text': u'United States', u'wikidata': u'Q30', u'id': u'country.9053006287256050'}], u'address': u'1151', u'relevance': 1, u'type': u'Feature', u'id': u'address.2415498141648290', u'place_name': u'1151 Folsom Street, San Francisco, California 94103, United States'}, {u'center': [-122.41, 37.78], u'geometry': {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [-122.41, 37.78]}, u'text': u'94103', u'place_type': [u'postcode'], u'properties': {}, u'bbox': [-122.42770549164, 37.7635596779962, -122.397810189758, 37.7880518462807], u'context': [{u'text': u'San Francisco', u'wikidata': u'Q62', u'id': u'place.15734669613361910'}, {u'short_code': u'US-CA', u'text': u'California', u'wikidata': u'Q99', u'id': u'region.11319063928738010'}, {u'short_code': u'us', u'text': u'United States', u'wikidata': u'Q30', u'id': u'country.9053006287256050'}], u'relevance': 0.75, u'type': u'Feature', u'id': u'postcode.13892342768265050', u'place_name': u'San Francisco, California 94103, United States'}, {u'center': [-120.351259, 36.149281], u'geometry': {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [-120.351259, 36.149281], u'interpolated': True}, u'text': u'Folsom Street', u'place_type': [u'address'], u'properties': {u'accuracy': u'interpolated'}, u'context': [{u'text': u'93210', u'id': u'postcode.15655570180150430'}, {u'text': u'Coalinga', u'wikidata': u'Q985263', u'id': u'place.11616473478769790'}, {u'short_code': u'US-CA', u'text': u'California', u'wikidata': u'Q99', u'id': u'region.11319063928738010'}, {u'short_code': u'us', u'text': u'United States', u'wikidata': u'Q30', u'id': u'country.9053006287256050'}], u'address': u'1151', u'relevance': 0.4, u'type': u'Feature', u'id': u'address.165808680526830', u'place_name': u'1151 Folsom Street, Coalinga, California 93210, United States'}, {u'center': [-121.270558, 37.935765], u'geometry': {u'omitted': True, u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [-121.270558, 37.935765], u'interpolated': True}, u'text': u'Folsom Street', u'place_type': [u'address'], u'properties': {u'accuracy': u'interpolated'}, u'context': [{u'text': u'Stockton Metropolitan Airport', u'id': u'neighborhood.289380'}, {u'text': u'95206', u'id': u'postcode.5171535940442000'}, {u'text': u'Stockton', u'wikidata': u'Q49240', u'id': u'place.8554008982780520'}, {u'short_code': u'US-CA', u'text': u'California', u'wikidata': u'Q99', u'id': u'region.11319063928738010'}, {u'short_code': u'us', u'text': u'United States', u'wikidata': u'Q30', u'id': u'country.9053006287256050'}], u'address': u'1151', u'relevance': 0.4, u'type': u'Feature', u'id': u'address.2752377031224260', u'place_name': u'1151 Folsom Street, Stockton, California 95206, United States'}, {u'center': [-121.3078506, 38.5879294], u'geometry': {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [-121.3078506, 38.5879294]}, u'text': u'Folsom Boulevard', u'place_type': [u'address'], u'properties': {u'accuracy': u'street'}, u'context': [{u'text': u'Cordova Gardens', u'id': u'neighborhood.289486'}, {u'text': u'95670', u'id': u'postcode.7919884525467840'}, {u'text': u'Rancho Cordova', u'wikidata': u'Q986928', u'id': u'place.5058833534899630'}, {u'short_code': u'US-CA', u'text': u'California', u'wikidata': u'Q99', u'id': u'region.11319063928738010'}, {u'short_code': u'us', u'text': u'United States', u'wikidata': u'Q30', u'id': u'country.9053006287256050'}], u'relevance': 0.398, u'type': u'Feature', u'id': u'address.8435179963733262', u'place_name': u'Folsom Boulevard, Rancho Cordova, California 95670, United States'}]}
```

I then get the coordinates of the output, using:

```
coordinates = result['features'][1]['center']
```

However, when I try and print `coordinates` (geo-coordinates) for this same output, I get:

```
[-122.41, 37.78]
```

How can I get this to print the full float of the coordinates?  Currently, it seems to be rounding the numbers to two decimal places.  I've tried using: `print ["%0.6f" % i for i in coordinates]` but this just adds zeros to the end of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the full float of those coordinates.

If you examine the json, you'll see that for *only* the second `center` (at index 1) there are two decimal places. The rest have at least six decimal places.

running:

```
for coordinates in result["features"]:
    print(coordinates["center"])
```

resulted in:

```
[-122.408767, 37.775679]
[-122.41, 37.78]
[-120.351259, 36.149281]
[-121.270558, 37.935765]
[-121.3078506, 38.5879294]
```